# if statement wont take variable 'a' and 'b' when declared in python if statement

Tags: python

I have been curious about how to simplify my work. But for now, my 
    problem is how to pass variables through functions and to get this If 
    statement to work. The variable a and b need to pass into the if 
    statement to check if the string is in the array '`colors`' or 
    '`other_colors`'

```
import random;
hot_spot=0;
colors = ['R','G','B','O','P']
other_colors =['RED','GREEN','BLUE','ORANGE','PURPLE']
guesser_array=[]


def code_maker():
    code_maker_array=[]
    for i in range(4):
        ran = random.randint(0,4)
        print (ran)
        code_maker_array.append(colors[ran])
        print(code_maker_array)
    return code_maker_array
x = code_maker()


def code_breaker():
    trys = 0;
    cbi = input('please put in r,g,b,o,p or red,green,blue,orange,purple_ ')
    cbi = cbi.upper()
    if ( isinstance(cbi,str) == True):
        print ('it is a string')
        print (cbi)
        for i in range(4):
            if (len(cbi)>=3):
                a = other_colors[i].find(cbi)
            else:
                b = colors[i].find(cbi)
            if (a >= 0 or b >= 0):
                print ('yummmeiabui aebfiahfu dsdsde')

y = code_breaker()


"""
def code_checker(x):
    print (x)

code_checker(x)
"""
```

Comment: Your code is only declaring either `a` or `b` because they're on different ends of the same if statement.  Therefore in the next if statement you'll never have both variables to compare, throwing a `NameError `.  You'll need to initialize `a` and `b` with a default value first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

hot_spot=0
colors = ['R','G','B','O','P']
other_colors =['RED','GREEN','BLUE','ORANGE','PURPLE']
guesser_array=[]


def code_maker():
    code_maker_array=[]
    for i in range(4):
        ran = random.randint(0,4)
        print (ran)
        code_maker_array.append(colors[ran])
        print(code_maker_array)
    return code_maker_array
x = code_maker()


def code_breaker():
    trys = 0;
    cbi = input('please put in r,g,b,o,p or red,green,blue,orange,purple_ ')
    cbi = cbi.upper()
    if ( isinstance(cbi,str) == True):
        print ('it is a string')
        print (cbi)
        for i in range(4):
            a=b=0                   #This line added
            if (len(cbi)>=3):
                a = other_colors[i].find(cbi)
            else:
                b = colors[i].find(cbi)
            if (a >= 0 or b >= 0):
                print ('yummmeiabui aebfiahfu dsdsde')

y = code_breaker()


"""
def code_checker(x):
    print (x)

code_checker(x)
"""
```

The variables `a` and `b` you have defined run out of scope as soon as their respective `if` blocks end. To prevent this, you can simply define them by initializing them to 0 (or any other value) outside of the if statement.

While Lucefer's answer simplified code a lot, I added this because defining variables in an outer scope like this is and modifying their values later on (in the if blocks in your case) is a very common practice, you might find it helpful somewhere else as well.

Comment: `a` and `b` are not out of score though.  Had they defined both variables within both `if...else...` both will still be accessible for the remainder of the function.  The issue is not where they defined `a` and `b`, but that they tried to access both while the program will only ever create either one in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

remove this whole code segment

```
 for i in range(4):
            if (len(cbi)>=3):
                a = other_colors[i].find(cbi)
            else:
                b = colors[i].find(cbi)
            if (a >= 0 or b >= 0):
                print ('yummmeiabui aebfiahfu dsdsde')
```

just simply add

```
  if( (cbi in other_colors) or (cbi in colors) ):
     print ('yummmeiabui aebfiahfu dsdsde')
```

Comment: how do I check the whole word rather than the letter? and thanks so much. I'm a beginner at this.

Comment: I thought, did you want to check whole the word. This will check that whole word is  in the any list that u provided not the letters